# Optimising using Hessian matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

I am bit perplexed in optimisation problem if the principal minor is zero. If the principal minor is zero does it mean that the Hessian matrix is always indefinite and the point of extremum will refer to saddle point?

Comment: you might want to check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935528/critical-points-characterization-of-real-function/936469#936469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be indefinite; it might be positive semidefinite as in
$$
H = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&2}
$$
for $f(x,y) = y^2$.  As a result, the extremum at $(0,0)$ is neither a strict local minimum/maximum nor a saddle point.

However, a principal minor of $0$ certainly means that $H$ can no longer be positive or negative definite.